Is it possible to lock/unlock a table by the current user using FireDAC components?
I have an application that uses Advantage Database Server, and I want to migrate it to PostgreSQL.
The application uses TAdsTable.AdsLockTable and TAdsTable.AdsUnlockTable to lock and unlock tables, ensuring that only the current user has access to the table.
This feature is particularly useful for adding new indexes to a table.
Do FireDAC components offer a similar feature, especially for PostgreSQL databases?
